# Add up values of same key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to count the tot values of sub dictionaries with same subkeys. I have a list containing the relevant keys `mylist`, I only need to count the total of the values for each element in the list.

```
mylist = ['age','answ1', 'answ2', 'answ3']
d = {'01': {'age':19, 'answ1':3, 'answ2':7, 'answ3':2}, '02': {'age':52, 'answ1':8, 'answ2':1, 'answ3':10},...}
```

I've tried

```
tot = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for ke, va in v.items():
        for i in mylist[0:]
            count=0
            if ke == i:
                count+=v[ke]
                tot.append(count)
```

but instead of the sum of the values with same key, I get the values of different keys in the order of appearance in the dictionary.
The expected outcome would be

```
tot = [71, 11, 8, 12]
```

What I get is

```
tot = [19, 3, 7, 2, 52, 8, 1, 10]
```

Comment: Do all sub dicts have the same keys and in the correct order?

Comment: @HeapOverflow no, they don't

Comment: Do all sub dicts have all keys in `mylist`, or might there be missing keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to store your result in a dictionary, you can create one with the keys from your list and calculate the results there.

```
result = {i: 0 for i in mylist}

for k, v in d.items():
    result['age'] += v['age']
    result['answ1'] += v['answ1']
    result['answ2'] += v['answ2']
    result['answ3'] += v['answ3']

result
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

However this does rely on the keys not changing, order should not matter.

EDIT

You can do this regardless of key names with the following update. Note it adds one extra iteration.

```
result = {i: 0 for i in mylist}
for k, v in d.items():
    for ke, va in v.items():
        result[ke] += v[ke]
```

Comment: Yes, the name of the keys are the same. The problem is that they are more than the 4 I have displayed, I think 20+, so is there a way to indicate the keys without inputting the name manually? Would it work if instead of `result['age'] += v['age']` etc I put `'result[k] += v[k]`?

Comment: `k` in your code points to `01` which is the key holding the dict with the values. You would need to iterate one more level to do so.

Comment: So I add `for ke, va in v.items()` and then I can do `result[ka] += v[ka]`?

Comment: Check my update, that will achieve the same without specifically calling the key name.

Comment: Thank you. Two more things, what do you mean it would add an extra iteration? Will it change the results? And, what does `i:0` mean in `result = {i: 0 for i in mylist}`?

Comment: It won't change the results, just referring to the code performing one more iteration over the values in the dicts. `i` is key name, `0` is the value of the key. This creates a dictionary from the keys in `mylist` and sets there values to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

With `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> ctr = sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
>>> [ctr[x] for x in mylist]
[71, 11, 8, 12]
```

Or:

```
>>> [sum(e[k] for e in d.values()) for k in mylist]
[71, 11, 8, 12]
```

In case some sub dicts can have keys missing, just use `e.get(k, 0)`. The `Counter` solution doesn't need it, it supplies zeros by default.

Hmm, since you now accepted a `dict` result solution...

```
>>> dict(sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter()))
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

Or maybe just

```
>>> sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
Counter({'age': 71, 'answ3': 12, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8})
```

Although these might have more keys than just the desired ones, if there are more in your data.

Comment: you mapped the Counter() function to values, and then another Counter in sum does what exactly?

Comment: Initial value, as the default is `0`, and `Counter` and `int` refuse to get added.

Comment: nice, thanks, so we could use `functools.reduce` too make it even more efficient? it takes first two elements if default value is not given. so 0 won't be there, just two counters then the result of their sum to other ones.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav I doubt it'll make a noteworthy difference. If the number of dictionaries is large, it might actually be slower due to function call overhead (of the function you give `reduce` as first argument).

Comment: well this is it, `functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,map(Counter,d.values()))` will give `Counter({'age': 71, 'answ3': 12, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8})`

Comment: ok, I learned something new. I have recently learned about reduce, so I'm trying to see its usefulness in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['age','answ1', 'answ2', 'answ3']
d = {'01': {'age':19, 'answ1':3, 'answ2':7, 'answ3':2}, '02': {'age':52, 'answ1':8, 'answ2':1, 'answ3':10}}

tot = [0] * len(mylist)
for k in d:
    for idx, i in enumerate(mylist):
        tot[idx] += d[k].get(i, 0)

print(tot)
```

Prints:

```
[71, 11, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
for i in mylist:
count=0
for k,v in d.items():
    for ke, va in v.items():
        if ke == i:
            count+=va
tot.append(count)
```

~

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using list comprehensions, `zip` and `map`. Firstly, we want to extract the corresponding values from each sub-dict:

```
>>> vals = [[v[k] for k in mylist] for v in d.values()]
>>> vals
[[19, 3, 7, 2], [52, 8, 1, 10]]
```

Now we want to perform an element-wise sum across all the sub-lists:

```
>>> result = map(sum, zip(*vals))
>>> list(result)
[71, 11, 8, 12]
```

---

Putting it all in one line:

```
>>> result = map(sum, zip(*([v[k] for k in mylist] for v in d.values())))
>>> list(result)
[71, 11, 8, 12]
```

This approach has the benefit of only accessing the keys that we want to build instead of constructing a full `Counter` and then afterwards extracting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing but different.

```
>>> import operator
>>> f = operator.itemgetter(*mylist)
>>> vals = map(f,d.values())
>>> sums = map(sum,zip(*vals))
>>> result = dict(zip(mylist,sums))
>>> result
{'age': 71, 'answ1': 11, 'answ2': 8, 'answ3': 12}
```

If you don't want the dict, skip that and use `result = list(sums)`